# Hide Gridview when the data is not present

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I have a Gridview that has filters that can fire off the emptydata template. However when this is displayed I can still see the outline of my gridview. How can I make the Gridview disappear when the data is not present?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.GridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
      this.GridView1.Visible = false; 
}
```

Comment: What i wanted was for the Gridview borders to be hidden. Databoud was the correct place to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Gridview id="gridview" ...... 
      Visible='<%# ((ICollection)gridview.DataSource).Count == 0 ? false : true %>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the control itself with the Visible property set to false, or hide its parent control (i.e. the containing panel).

Comment: sounds great...but how can i do that in code and where? Gridview databound? how can i get access to the emptydata template in code?

Comment: GridView is an ASP.NET control, which means it will have a 'Visible' property, allowing you to show or hide the control itself.

GridView.Visible = false;

will prevent the control from being rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `DataSource` NULL, and re-`Bind()` the `GridView`, and it should hide itself!

```
myGridView.DataSource = null;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Besides be careful using `.Visible` as finding it later could be impossible. If you must use `.Visible = false;` I suggest using `myGridview.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");`